# Django, Django-template. Как выводить на одну страницу объекты разной высоты, в одной строке bootstrap row, в несколько рядов?

Tags: css, html5, django, bootstrap, шаблоны

Django templates вывод статей по строчно 4 штуки.

Вопрос в том что мой объект получает высоту по тому сколько есть строк в нем. Так как высота различается

```
float: left;
```

отрабатывает не правильно и строки обрываются не через 4 как задумывалось а как попало. Хочу использовать .row класс и каждый раз в .row выводить по 4 объекта. Проблема в том что не могу найти counter. Что бы как в python3

```
if a % b == 0:
    print('</div> <div class="row" ')
else:
    print('<div class="item">')
```

думаю

```
forloop.counter
```

предназначен для этой цели но как правильно использовать так и не нашел. Знаю о mansonary js, использовать его уже очень затратно по времени.

Answer (score 0):

Привет!

Попробуй сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            {% for item in items %}

                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

       </div> <!-- end row -->

   </div> <!-- end container -->
```

Где `if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4` - проверка на нужное к-во элементов в цикле.